# Натсройка .htaccess (RewriteEngine)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть URL http://site.ru/index.php?temp=main
Как заменить его на http://site.ru/main

(У меня получилось только так, http://site.ru/page/main

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?temp=$1 [L]`

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?temp=$1 [L]
```

Ответ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?temp=?([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Не работает ;(.